# Building OpenWrt 19.07 on Ubuntu 16.04 will failed since the GLIBC doesn’t match

Tags: openwrt

**Building OpenWrt 19.07 on Ubuntu 16.04**

```
scripts/config/conf: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by scripts/config/conf)
```

Obviously，seems the toolchain itself will be built also.
If moving to Ubuntu 18.04， the building will work since Glibc matches.

- OpenWrt 19.07 toolchain: GCC 7.5.0 and Glibc 2.27
- Ubuntu 16.04 default: GCC 5.4.0 and Glibc 2.23
- Ubuntu 18.04 default: GCC 7.5.0 and Glibc 2.27

**The question is, if insisted to build on Ubuntu 16.04, how to make it work?**

To simply upgrade GLIBC version on Ubuntu 16.04 from 2.23 to 2.27 is not the right way since this will lead system under risk or crash.

I noticed the feature in `make menuconfig`

```
[*] Package the OpenWrt-based Toolchain
```

I copied the toolchain package `/bin/targets/x86/64/openwrt-toolchain-x86-64_gcc-7.5.0_musl.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2` which is built and generated in Ubuntu 18.04 HOST and extract to Ubuntu 16.04 under openwrt directory `build_dir/toolchain-x86_64_gcc-7.5.0_musl` , it still didn't work.

Comment: Build it in a docker container?

Comment: Thanks very much.  Docker will work.  But I still want to know if there is a tricky way to do this.